# can we decrypt a file which is encrypted with basic java AES encryption using swift?

Tags: java, swift, encryption, aes

here is my java encryption code

```
 try
 {
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFilePath);


        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("secret_key_here".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[8];
while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    fos.write(d, 0, b);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
cis.close();
 }

 catch(  IOException | InvalidKeyException |NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e)
  {

System.out.println(e);
  }
```

And i am getting the encrypted file in that path specified, i can decrypt it in android using the decrypt code.

but when i use swift to decrypt the same, the file is not decrypted.

is it actually possible to decrypt an file which is encrypted by java AES be decrypted through swift.

Here is my swift decryption code

```
//fetching content from file
let fileContent = try! Data(contentsOf:urlPath!)

 //secret key

let keyData = "secret_key_here"//same key for encryption

    let data = Data(keyData.utf8)
//decrypting
let decryptedDta = AES.decrypt(fileContent, key: data)
//converting to string
let decryptedDta_String =  String(decoding: decryptedDta!, as: UTF8.self)
//writing to file
 let fileManager = FileManager.default
 do {

    let path = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    let fileURL = path.appendingPathComponent("newfile_1.xhtml")

    print("fileURL == ",fileURL)



    try decryptedDta_String.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

} catch {

    print("error creating file")

}
```

but the file is still encrypted. is this actually possible?

can we decrypt a file which is encrypted via java AES be decrypted through swift? please help

Comment: Never use `String.getBytes()`! Use [`getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) and pass the specific [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) you need, e.g. from `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`.

Comment: Yes this is possible, the only thing to keep in mind is the endianness of Java and Swift. Thing 2 to keep in mind is that Java does not have Unsigned types and Swift does.

Comment: @Murf can you please tell me how to achieve it?